# How can i use a variable in onClickListener of two buttons?

Tags: android, variables, onclicklistener

I want to use a variable in two OnClickListener of two buttons.
I am trying to register a user by verifying his mobile no by a verification code. I want to use this code in OnClickListener of "Verify" button to display a Dilog BoX.
How can I use this integer variable "verificationCode" in these OnClickListeners.
Following is my code

```
package com.deavnet.schoolapp;

import com.deavnet.schoolapp.R;
import com.deavnet.schoolapp.R.layout;
import com.deavnet.schoolapp.R.menu;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.R.string;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import java.util.Random;



public class Verify extends Activity {

    final int verificationCode=0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.verify_activity);

        // get the References of views
        final  EditText editTextMobileNo =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextMobileNo);
        final EditText editConfirmMobileNo=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextConfirmMobileNo);
        final Button btnSend=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
        final EditText editTextVerificationCode=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextVerificationCode);
        final Button btnVerify=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonVerify);


        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String mbno=editTextMobileNo.getText().toString();
                String confirmMbno=editConfirmMobileNo.getText().toString();
                String enteredCode=editTextVerificationCode.getText().toString();
                int verificationCodeEntered= Integer.parseInt(enteredCode);


                if(mbno.equals(""))
                {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                }
                else if(mbno!=confirmMbno)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mobile Number do not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    int min = 1000;
                    int max = 9999;
                    Random r = new Random();
                    int i1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;

                    int verificationCode = sendSMS(mbno,i1);
                }
            }
        });

        btnVerify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String enteredCode=editTextVerificationCode.getText().toString();
                int verificationCodeEntered= Integer.parseInt(enteredCode);
                dilogfun(verificationCodeEntered);
            }
        });
    }
    public int sendSMS(String mbno, int code) {

        try{

        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(mbno, null,""+code+"" , null, null);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("msg error", ""+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return code;
    }

    public boolean dilogfun(int verificationCodeEntered)
    {
        if(verificationCode==verificationCodeEntered)
        {
            // Creating alert Dialog with one Button

            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    Verify.this).create();

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("Regestration");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("Congratcs... Registration Successfull...");

            // Setting Icon to Dialog
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.tick);

            // Setting OK Button
            alertDialog.setButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            // Write your code here to execute after dialog
                            // closed
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Thank You...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.show();
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login_activity, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Hoping for best results...
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Remove `int` from following statement in your code.

```
int verificationCode = sendSMS(mbno,i1);
```

Because you have already declared this variable globally in the following statement of your code.

```
final int verificationCode=0;
```

Once you have removed this `int` then this variable can also be used in both listeners.

**EDIT**

Also follow  `Manmohan's and Ari's` comments.

Comment: also needed final to be removed from int declartion

Comment: "The final field Verify.verificationCode cannot be assigned" is the error I received after doing this.

Comment: final variable can be assigned only at the time of declaration, you cannot assign value to that variable later, so remove final, just use int, or you can use static int if you wish

Comment: Is there any way to check if user has registered once then app should diplay menu directly. If not then above verification screen should be displayed.

Comment: @ApekshaPawar u can ask a new que for this, if i answer u here then in 1 line u can use SharedPrefrences for check your condition.

Comment: Agree with @Manmohan Under one title only relevant questions should be asked. Because its easy for others to read this post and get help. ApekshaPawar For new questions start new thread.